# How does prolog run through recursive queries using succ?

Tags: prolog, successor-arithmetics

Can someone explain to me why this prolog query works the way it does. The definition is:

```
add(0,Y,Y). 
add(succ(X),Y,succ(Z)):- add(X,Y,Z).
```

Given this:

```
?-  add(succ(succ(succ(0))),  succ(succ(0)),  R).
```

Heres the trace of the query:

```
Call:  (6)  add(succ(succ(succ(0))),  succ(succ(0)),  R) 

Call:  (7)  add(succ(succ(0)),  succ(succ(0)),  _G648) 

Call:  (8)  add(succ(0),  succ(succ(0)),  _G650) 

Call:  (9)  add(0,  succ(succ(0)),  _G652) 

Exit:  (9)  add(0,  succ(succ(0)),  succ(succ(0))) 

Exit:  (8)  add(succ(0),  succ(succ(0)),  succ(succ(succ(0)))) 

Exit:  (7)  add(succ(succ(0)),  succ(succ(0)), 
                                              succ(succ(succ(succ(0))))) 

Exit:  (6)  add(succ(succ(succ(0))),  succ(succ(0)), 
                                                succ(succ(succ(succ(succ(0))))))
```

The part that confused me the most about that tutorial was the fact that in the first argument, the succ is stripped, and it recurses. While recursing though, R gains a succ... HOW?! Also, where does the zero come from at the first exit (9)? I am new to prolog, and I am trying to understand the language for a homework. Any help much appreciated.

Note: for anyone interested, the link to this tutorial is http://www.learnprolognow.org/lpnpage.php?pagetype=html&pageid=lpn-htmlse9

Comment: Usually, `succ/1` is written as `s/1`. Please look at answers labelled [tag:successor-arithmetics].

Answer (score 1, accepted):

***"where does the zero come from at the first exit (9)?"***

The call `add(0,  succ(succ(0)),  _G652)` is unified with the first clause that says that if the first argument of `add` is zero, then the second and the third are the same. In this particular situatiob variable `_G652` becomes `succ(succ(0))`.

***"While recursing though, R gains a succ... HOW?!"***

This is the result of the application of the second clause. This clause states (roughly) that you first strip `succ` from the first argument, then call `add` recursively, and, finally, add another "layer" of `succ` to the third argument coming back from this recursive call.

The predicate `add` is nothing but a direct implementation of addition in Peano arithmetics: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Peano_axioms#Addition

Comment: I see what you are saying, I am understanding this a little more. What I was not understanding was that the head of the rule is also doing something, I just assumed it did nothing until the body was proved.

Answer (score 4):

You see, `call` and `exit` are `verbs`, actions that the interpreter takes attempting to solve the query you pose. Then a trace exposes details of actual work done, and lets you view it in historical perspective.

When Prolog must choice a rule (a `call`), it uses the `name` you give it (so called `functor`), and attempts to to `unify` each argument in the head of the rule. Then we say usually that Prolog considers also the `arity`, i.e. number of arguments, for selection.

`Unification` attempts to 'make equals' two terms, and the noteworthy results are so called `bindings` of variables. You already know that variables are those names starting `Uppercase`. Such names identify unspecified values in rules, i.e. are `placeholders` for arguments. To avoid confusion, when Prolog shows the trace, variables are renamed so that we can identify them, because the relevant detail it's the `identities` or bindings established during the proof.

Then you see such `_G648` symbols in trace. They stay for the *yet to be instanced* arguments of the called goal, namely `R` and `Z`. R is unique (occurs just in top level call), so this Prolog kindly keep the user friendly name, but Z come from the program, potentially occurs multiple times, then got renamed.

To answer this query

```
?-  add(succ(succ(succ(0))),  succ(succ(0)),  R).
```

Prolog first attempts to match

```
add(0,Y,Y).
```

and fail because succ(succ(succ(0)) can't be made equal to 0.
Then attempts

```
add(succ(X),Y,succ(Z)) :- add(X,Y,Z).
```

thus must solve these bindings (to the left the caller' terms):

```
succ(succ(succ(0))) = succ(X)
succ(succ(0)) = Y
R = Z
```

You can see why X becomes `succ(succ(0))`, and we have a new goal to prove, i.e. the rule body `add(X,Y,Z)` with the bindings just established:

add(succ(succ(0)),succ(succ(0)),_G648)

and so on... until X become `0` and the goal matches

`add(0,Y,Y).`

Then Y becomes succ(succ(0)), and noteworthy also give a value to `Z` in the calling rule.

HTH

Answer (score 0):

The (hopefully) more legible trace with more annotations is:

```erlang
 (6) Call:  add(succ(succ(succ(0))),  succ(succ(0)),  R)          % R     = succ(_G648)
      (7) Call:  add(succ(succ(0)),  succ(succ(0)),  _G648)       % _G648 = succ(_G650) 
           (8) Call:  add(succ(0),  succ(succ(0)),  _G650)        % _G650 = succ(_G652) 
                (9) Call:  add(0,  succ(succ(0)),  _G652)         % _G652 = succ(succ(0))
                (9) Exit:  add(0,  succ(succ(0)),  succ(succ(0)))       
           (8) Exit:  add(succ(0),  succ(succ(0)),  succ(succ(succ(0)))) 
      (7) Exit:  add(succ(succ(0)),  succ(succ(0)), succ(succ(succ(succ(0))))) 
 (6) Exit:  add(succ(succ(succ(0))),  succ(succ(0)), succ(succ(succ(succ(succ(0))))))
```

As you can see, the four exits are redundant, the final answer *is already known* at the point of `(9) Exit`; only one exit is enough at that point:

```erlang
     %     R = succ(_G648)
     %              _G648 = succ(_G650) 
     %                           _G650 = succ(_G652) 
     %                                        _G652 = succ(succ(0))
     % thus,
     %     R = succ(        succ(        succ(        succ(succ(0)) )))
```

That is indeed what happens under the tail call optimization, as the predicate definition *is* indeed tail recursive and the result under `R` is built in a top-down manner, with the "hole" gradually being filled by instantiation of the logical variables. So the `succ( _ )` is not added *after* the recursive call, but is established *before* it. This is also the essence of the tail recursion modulo cons optimization.